# Gunicorn behind apache link to localhost

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy, gunicorn

I have a gunicorn serving a flask application behind Apache using mod_proxy.

Gunicorn is on `http://localhost:8080/`. Let's say my server is on `http://example.com/`

Sometimes when I post an invalid link to my server (like forgetting the trailing), let's say `http://example.com/with-no-trailing-slash`, the user is redirected to `http://localhost:8080/with-no-trailing-slash` which is not valid because there is no server on the client machine.

Do you know why it behaves like that? And how to fix this behavior?

To start gunicorn I do this: `sudo gunicorn -b localhost:8080 app:app`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example.com

DocumentRoot /opt/example

<Proxy *>
    AuthType basic
    AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
    SetEnv proxy-chain-auth On
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

# Let apache serve static files
ProxyPass /robots.txt !
ProxyPass /favicon.ico !
ProxyPass /static/ !
Alias /static/ /opt/example/app/static/

# Gunicorn handle the others
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/


# robots.txt et favicon.ico sont dans /path/to/django/project/static/
Alias /robots.txt /path/to/django/project/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /path/to/django/project/static/favicon.ico

Alias /favicon.ico /path/to/django/project/static/favicon.ico

<Directory /path/to/django/project>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you need another config file, let me know!

Comment: Typically I would expect that to be the result of a trailing slash in your ProxyPass directive instead of omitting that. e.g. `ProxyPass /app/ http://localhost:8080/app/` versus `ProxyPasss /app http://..../app`

Comment: Yes, post the relevant sections of the config files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the reverse mapping which is precisely useful to Apache for redirection URLs rewriting. In 99% of cases, the forward and reverse mappings are the same.

Add this :

```
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

And reload Apache.